# How to read all NetCDF files in one directory and create one single NetCDF file with the same variable atributes of one the files?

Tags: multidimensional-array, 3d, netcdf

I have hundreds of 3D Netcdf files in one directory. I would like to first read all Netcdf data exist in the directory at once in a for loop and create one NetCDF file with the same variables and attributes of one of the single files, such as `-Fill_value` `missing_value` `Lon` and `Lat`. There are several variables in one file that are belongs to the same month.

The dimensions of each single data: `1x180x360` and at the end my file should be `280x180x360`

All data contain the same variables and attributes.?

```
cdo merge file.nc file2.nc file.nc new_file.nc
```

does not work, because I am working on windows and Python 3.7.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

file1 = 'D:\DATA\gls_SWE5K_202001_NHEMI_SSMIS_v0.nc'
data = Dataset(file1, 'r')

TW=  data.variables['tw'][:]
Pre = data.variables['pre'][:]
Tem = data.variables['tem'][:]
Lonn = data.variables['lon'][:]
Lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
Time = data.variables['time'][:]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Comment: hi Ehsan, it is very unclear what you want to do , is it a simple cdo mergetime of files? where does the python come in? please try to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alongside with `cdo`, we can open multi netcdf files at once with python `xarray` as follow, which is more straightforward:

```
xarray.open_mfdataset('path/to/my/files/*.nc', concat_dim="time")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Windows 10, as you should be, it is possible to install Ubuntu from the Microsoft store, assuming it is your own machine.

From there it is straightforward to install `cdo` or `nco`. Personally I would use the latter, as it is a more lightweight package, and you only need to use `ncrcat` command.

If you have no permissions to install anything, I'm afraid you probably have the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Dear Robert, 

Thanks for your reply. Actually I have linux and already installed cdo on the my linux machine embedded in windows 10. 

That works fine. 

     `cdo mergetime *.nc Goutput_file.nc `